# Database Design for large datasets

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, large-data, database-partitioning

I'm currently working on a database table desing where we will have a few hundred million records in it and I wonder what will be the best way of managing it. With these kind of datasets we will eventually run into maintenance issues like that a table restore or an alter table will take a long time. Now I have some ideas on how to handle that but maybe there's a better way?

Since our data is more relevant the newer it is, we could split it up into a short time range (e.g. last 30 days) and the old dataset (older than last 30 days). For this I see two possibilities:

**Splitting it up into two partitions, the current partition and the old data partition**

Advantages:

- A Table Restore of the current data partition would be fast since it's not that big. In a case of emergency, we would restore this first and bring the system up again with just that data. This would be an acceptable scenario for the user
- We could read / write to the tables as normal - so no specific application logic needed

Disadvantages:

- Migration scripts (alter table, we can use online but that doesn't work with every use case if I get that right) take a long time since they are still run against both of the partitions. A solution to this would be to take the old data partition offline for the user and run it in the background. So the user would not have access during that time to the old data but that would be ok. Is something like this possible?

**Splitting it manually into two tables and moving data with a nightly job. Ontop we put a view to select data**

Advantages:

- We could take the old data table offline by not include it in the view anymore and run alter table scripts. Once it is done, put it back into the view. Since the user wouldn't find the data anymore, he will also not be able to modify it
- A Table Restore would be quick since we would restore the current table first, update the view and let the user use it again. The restore of the old data table would take a while but that's ok

Disadvantages:

- Since it's a view, we can only select through it. If it comes to modifying data, we would need to write update queries for both tables because a user want's to update old data. So from an application perspective it needs custom logic

So my question is, what is best practice in such kind of a scenario? What would you suggest doing?

Thanks

Comment: You could also sub partition on year and month using more partitions.. i assume you will use InnoDB engine? Most DDL statements on the InnoDB engine can run Online which means the tables or partitions will not get locked while alterd

Comment: Are you talking about inserting 300M rows in a year?  That's a mere 10/second.  I don't get excited until it is 100/sec.

Answer (score 1):

Few hundred million is a lot, but not a *large dataset* for today. Large datasets have billions of records. The question here is i think, *how fast your data is growing?* and *what type of query you run against it?* If your data is growing very slow, any database software can handle that amount fast enough even without partition. If it is growing fast, it might be a good idea make some partitioning.

If you have OLTP workload, so small queries with a high latency but a lot of them, it is a good idea to keep hot data in separate place. If they depend on time, I suggest you to use native partitioning based on a datetime column, partitioned by year. This way, most queries based on recent data will only check latest partition and maybe very small piece of your whole dataset.

If the *recent* means very short period like 1 month, then the above method is not enough although still useful. So, you could create another *hot-data-table* on top of it. Now you have a big data table partitioned by year (has always all data), and a small table that has recent data. To come over the disadvantages, you could do this:

- UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE
- All queries go to main table; a trigger for each operation will duplicate the operation on hot-data table, if necessary. (database level logic)
- Or you can send relevant queries to both tables and ensure they are consistent in application level (application level logic). This one might be more performant, as mysql triggers can slow down the database more.
- SELECT queries will go to new table depending on query, otherwise main table (partitioning by year helps here for performance). Query splitting can be also done with a proxy if you want to be flexible. [Proxysql](https://proxysql.com/) can handle that easily. It has other benefits such as caching and connection multiplexing as well.
- To discard older data from hot-data table, you can execute an event each day to delete records older than 1 month. If you have 10s of thousands to delete, you should delete them in smaller chunks to prevent issues like locking, lagging and big resource consumption. Another way could be using a *is_deleted* column to identify outdated records, and partition by that. Deleting the partition at any time is instant.

For non-blocking DDL operations, there are open source tools to migrate your schema online without degrading much of the performance. Check out [pt-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html) and [ghost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost).

Comment: You can’t define large as a number off records In your question you are directing more or less to the big data term.. in mine opinion the big data term volume/size condition would be if you handle data which is to large to store in the servers RAM. Meaning 9 Gb on a 8 Gb RAM can be considerd “big data” and on a 128 Gb well “small data”.. Immers it is known database server are slower then disk I/o is needed to process the database without accessing it from memory

Comment: @RaymondNijland you are right in theory but the title of question says “large dataset”, and not mentioning resources he has. So i wanted to point generally that few hundred million is nothing to handle for todays softwares

Comment: Yes the commit was not meant to "attack" your answer in anny way, also i noticed this comment *"All queries go to main table; a trigger for each operation will duplicate the operation on hot-data table, if necessary. (database level logic)"*  A better approach could/might be to switch over to a other database system (like PostgreSQL) what natively supports [materialized views/tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) which can hold table expressions as defined in SQL 2003 .. iám still waiting on MySQL to support this feature

Comment: I didnt get offended :) Also, i agree wiith materialization but didnt mention cuz the guestion tagged mysql. However, vitess.io for mysql sharding added that feature recently and it looks great. You should Check it out if you are interested.

Comment: I suggest that the Trigger costs more than simply having a single table (`PARTITIONed` or not).

Answer (score 0):

(Focusing on old vs new data)

If the table is ordered somewhat chronologically and you mostly access the "new" data, then a significant amount of caching, and performance that it gives, is builtin automatically.

Just be sure to use InnoDB and have the `PRIMARY KEY` be an `AUTO_INCREMENT` (or start with a `DATETIME`).

Let's run some numbers.  If you have 300M rows in a table, and each row takes 100 bytes (an easy rule of thumb), then the table's data takes 30GB.  There will be some more for indexes and other tables.  If you are running on a server with 64GB of RAM (not unreasonable *today*), then everything might fit in RAM and not need much I/O.

If, instead, you had only 8GB of RAM and most of the activity was in the latest 10% of the table, then, again, it will be well cached.

(Note:  I/O is the biggest *hardware* component of performance.)

What usually trips up designs of large tables is indexing, query formulation, or even overall architecture.  But, since you have no details on such, I skip that.

You mentioned a crude, manual, way of partitioning the table.  There is something built in: `PARTITIONing`.  But it is *not* likely to help inserts, updates, or selects, so I don't recommend it without some further discussion.

If you will eventually purge "old" data (say after a year), then `PARTITIONing` *is* a good idea.  I would use weekly partitions if the table is to hold only 1 year's data.  We can discuss this further if you need it.  *But* note that the only benefit is with deleting the old data via `DROP PARTITION`; partitioning is.

`SUBPARTITIONs` don't help any.